# Open Google Drive file with new Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have list of file with I downloaded from Google Drive. Those Files have different mimeType like

```
"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
"application/vnd.google-apps.file"
"application/pdf"
"video/mpeg"
"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12"
```

how to open those file in new intent?

also to open file I should use id(`0B_uvNTGVtbi****zOS1WY78yVlU`) or title (`RJ_****_462324_20417.pdf`)

for now I am using, but "System Android was stopped" :)

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(localFile.getTitle()));
        myIntent.setType("*/*");
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Choose an application to open with:");
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When you say 'I have a list ...', please specify a list of what (file titles, file IDs,....)

Comment: list of files and folder (not physical files) with all fields like title, id, mimetype, last modify, trashed, stared etc. those list I get by Google Drive Api.

Comment: What API did you use to get the list? [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)  or [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk)?

Answer (score 0):

If by "opening" the file you mean to allow user to choose the app in which they should open you need to use the URL of the drive file and send an ACTION_VIEW intent with this url (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) for details). If the user doesn't have Drive App installed, the url will be opened up in a browser otherwise user will get an option to open it in DriveApp or the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you are using file title as URI which is not a valid URI:

```
myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(localFile.getTitle()))//this is wrong
```

you need to call:

```
myIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(localFile))// use this instead
```